# VSTS Angular 5 npm run failure (dep not found - dep from angular-cli)

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, angular5, azure-pipelines

I upgraded to angular 5 and noticed that my build keeps failing on VSTS (locally it works fine)

It looks like a dep from angular-cli cannot be found. Any solutions?

Build Output

```
[command]C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" run build -- "--env=nightlybuild""
2018-01-29T19:06:23.9805943Z 
2018-01-29T19:06:23.9807508Z > aes-web-portal@0.0.0 build d:\a\1\s\AESWebPortal\aes-web-portal
2018-01-29T19:06:23.9808541Z > ng build "--env=nightlybuild"
2018-01-29T19:06:23.9809016Z 
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8023599Z Cannot find module 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8041057Z Error: Cannot find module 'uglifyjs-webpack-plugin'
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8041907Z     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8042680Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8043360Z     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8044136Z     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8046229Z     at Object.<anonymous> (d:\a\1\s\AESWebPortal\aes-web-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\production.js:13:24)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8047263Z     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8048144Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8048743Z     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8049274Z     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8049758Z     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8050286Z     at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8050774Z     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8051383Z     at Object.<anonymous> (d:\a\1\s\AESWebPortal\aes-web-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-configs\index.js:9:10)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8052009Z     at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8052499Z     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2018-01-29T19:06:26.8052975Z     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Comment: This may be related: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9427

Comment: Based on the log, it caused by the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin. And what's the version of the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin do you use? What if you update the version to 1.1.8?